# How use multiple style rules on one element in HTML?

Tags: html

I've input the following;

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;" style="font-size:250%;">Text here</h1>
```

The text is now aligned in the center of the page but the font size won't increase. I understand that you can use numerous style elements at the same so my code must be wrong. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks for taking the time to help a newbie like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two attributes with the same name. Basic syntax is like this:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center; font-size:250%;">Text here</h1>
```

That said, it's usually better to do styling either in an external stylesheet, like this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="my-styles.css">
```

Or with an embedded style tag, like this:

```
<style>
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:250%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know how to resolve your post. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `style` property twice. Multiple styles can be added like this:

`<h1 style="text-align:center; font-size:250%;">Text here</h1>`

Notice the `;` separating the styles

Answer (score 0):

You could use what @isherwood is suggesting.
Or use a CSS solution which is cleaner and generally more recommended.
You would use this HTML:

```
<h1 class="myHeading">Text here</h1>
```

And this CSS:

```
.myHeading {
text-align:center;
font-size:250%;
}
```